# Handling the DataSource property of a DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

In a Visual Studio 2012 project, I have a DataGridView: I assign a list of Items to its DataSource:

```
DGListInvoiceItems.DataSource = Me.currentlistItem
DGListInvoiceItems.Refresh()
lSummaryListItems.Text = "Summary List Items in Invoice nr. " & currentlistItem.Count
Dim irows As Integer = DGListInvoiceItems.RowCount
```

`currentListItem` Is dynamically updated with the following routine:

```
Sub UpdateListItems()
    Dim lineItem As New InvoiceLineItemStru
    lineItem.ProductCode = product. Productcode
    lineItem.UnitPrice = product. ProductUnitPric
    lineItem.Quantity =cbQuantity.SelectedItem
    lineItem.ItemTotal =lineItem.UnitPrice * lineItem.Quantity
    currentlistItem.Add(lineItem)`
End Sub
```

After adding the first item, the DataGrid displays the item in the list.
When I add another one, `currentListItem` contains 2 Items but the DataGridView only displays 1 as you can see in the figure: (don't know how to insert the photo).

How come? How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried setting `DGListInvoiceItems.DataSource = Nothing` before setting a, possibly new, List of (something). Also, could you show what this list contains and how it's created?

Comment: The currentListItem Is dynamically updated
with the following routine
Sub UpdateListItems()
      Dim lineItem As New InvoiceLineItemStru
      lineItem.ProductCode is product. Productcode
      lineItem.UnitPrice is product. ProductUnitPrice property
      lineItem.Quantity : cbQuantity.SelectedItem
      lineItem.ItemTotal : lineItem.UnitPrice : lineItem.Quantity
      currentlistItem.Add(lineItem)
   End Sub

Comment: After adding the first item, the DataGrid displays the item in the list.
When I add another one, the currentListItem contains 2 Items but the DataGrid displays only 1 as you can see in the figure:  (don't know how to insert the photo )
Thank you for everything

Comment: Please, update the question with your current code, don't post it in comments. -- Your list doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`; as a consequence, the List changes are not notified. See my first comment, as a possible solution. Otherwise, implement the Interface or use a BindingSource (or both). The `BindingSource` creates a `BindingListSource`, which could be enough in your case. But, you have to update the BindingSource, adding elements to its underlying `List`.

Comment: Another possible solution is to use a DataTable instead of a `List<class>`.

Comment: But the Data in the list is created when needed, it's just to be shown because it's then used for other operations and doesn't come from a database table.
Thank you

Comment: A DataTable's content doesn't need to come from a database. It's an object like the others, as your List of `something`. You can use it the same way. But, I suggested other solutions. Start from the first one.

Comment: ok tanks I'll try it with a DataTable

Comment: Try first setting the DataSource property to `null` (`Nothing`), then set the updated List. Using a BindingSource is also quite simple and provides good options. A DataTable is very *friendly*, in relation to automatic updates and data bindings.

Comment: ok Is very good Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Declare "lineItem"  as global Variable in form.

```
  Dim lineItem As New InvoiceLineItemStru
Sub UpdateListItems()
    lineItem.ProductCode = product. Productcode
    lineItem.UnitPrice = product. ProductUnitPric
    lineItem.Quantity =cbQuantity.SelectedItem
    lineItem.ItemTotal =lineItem.UnitPrice * lineItem.Quantity
    currentlistItem.Add(lineItem)`
End Sub
```

Comment: Tanchs for all Mary and nanda9894

Answer (score 0):

I created 2 classes, the `Product` class and the `InvoiceLineItem`. Instead of repeating properties in the `InvoiceLineItem` class, I had the second class `Inherit` the first.

```
Public Class Product
    Public Property ProductCode As Integer
    Public Property UnitPrice As Decimal

    Public Sub New(code As Integer, price As Decimal)
        ProductCode = code
        UnitPrice = price
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class InvoiceLineItem
    Inherits Product

    Public Property Quantity As Integer
    Public Property ItemTotal As Decimal

    Public Sub New(code As Integer, price As Decimal, quant As Integer)
        MyBase.New(code, price)
        Quantity = quant
        ItemTotal = UnitPrice * Quantity
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the `Form.Load` I manually set up (setting `.AutoGenerateColumns` to false) the columns so they would make more sense as an invoice line item. I then mapped the properties of the class to the fields in the grid.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    With DataGridView1.Columns
        .Add("colCode", "Product Code")
        .Add("colQuant", "Quantity")
        .Add("colPrice", "Unit Price")
        .Add("colLineTotal", "Total")
    End With
    With DataGridView1
        .Columns("colCode").DataPropertyName = "ProductCode"
        .Columns("colQuant").DataPropertyName = "Quantity"
        .Columns("colPrice").DataPropertyName = "UnitPrice"
        .Columns("colLineTotal").DataPropertyName = "ItemTotal"
    End With
    DataGridView1.DataSource = lst
End Sub
```

Create a Form level variable to hold the list of invoice line items. The update list Sub is called from an event and the actual data could come from anywhere.

```
Private lst As New List(Of InvoiceLineItem)

Private Sub UpdateListItems(p As Product, quant As Integer)
    Dim lineItem As New InvoiceLineItem(p.ProductCode, p.UnitPrice, quant)
    lst.Add(lineItem)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    UpdateListItems(New Product(123, 17.43D), 10)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGridView1.DataSource = lst
End Sub
```